# elif [ "$input" = "no" ]; then go the next statement

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

input=""

echo "Does a wall needs to be sent?"
read input

if [ "$input" = "yes" ]; then
    echo "Sending message to all user about a system reboot or shutdown"|wall
elif [ "$input" = "no" ]; then
    exit
fi

echo "Is this a reboot or shutdown?"
read input

if [ "$input" = "reboot" ]; then
    echo "System is rebooting"
    shutdown -r +1
elif [ "$input" = "shutdown" ]; then
    echo "System is about to shutdown"
    shutdown -h +1
fi

echo "Goodbye"
```

what I'm trying to figure out is that if I dont send a wall than I want to get prompt the statement echo "Is this a reboot or shutdown?"

how would I go about doing than instead of having the script exit when i dont want to send a wall

Comment: You are exiting the script if the user responds `no` to the `wall` question.  Do you really need to exit script if that is the case?  What is the default behavior? Reboot or shutdown?

Comment: I try to modify the the script by removing "exit" and "fi" but it appears to not work. I don't need to exit the script when I click "no". When I click "no" I want the statement "is this a reboot or shutdown"

Answer (score 1):

Remove the two lines:

```
elif [ "$input" = "no" ]; then
    exit
```

and you should be good.

Comment: Your Awesome !!!!

Comment: I see you put reboot="reboot" so how does that all link up. Sorry if I'm newb but this is my first linux class

Comment: That was a long-winded answer that I deleted.  This one is simpler.  The other option is to use two variables and I had arbitrarily called the variable as `reboot`.